# Python Selenium Webdriver change url after login and remain logged in

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Currently creating a **scraper** where I scrape sales data, but too see them I must first login and navigate to it.

Manual navigation is possible by pressing a bunch of buttons, but if I know the end url, is it somehow possible to navigate to the url after I have automated the logging process with Selenium webdriver?

See example:

```
driver.get("https://ui8.net/")
print("Trying to log in on UI8")

driver.implicitly_wait(15)

driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "/html/body/div[1]/header/div[2]/div[2]/a").click()

email_input = driver.find_element_by_id("login-email")
password_input = driver.find_element_by_id("login-password")

email_input.send_keys(data["login"])
password_input.send_keys(data["pw"])

driver.find_element_by_id("login-button").click()

print("Logged in on UI8")
# TODO: Somehow need to get to this url https://ui8.net/affiliate/sales
```

If I simply do `driver.get("https://ui8.net/affiliate/sales")` after I have logged in, it is going to open a new tab but I wont be logged in anymore.

I can simply press and hover over a bunch of things until I reach that url, but I feel like I can just href to it somehow?

Anyone has any ideas? There is the `driver.navigate().to()` but this does not seem to work in python.

Comment: Strange `driver.get("https://ui8.net/affiliate/sales")` this should not open a new tab it should load in same tab.

Comment: It does not open a new tab, my mistake.
But it does not remain logged in

Comment: May be a session cookies would work ? Not sure it depends on Application to application, but I guess you can try that out.

Comment: @cruisepandey Cookies was hard, I did it with using chrome profiles and logging in before hand and then just starting chrome with that profile.